# What do Elements of the Tensor Product Look Like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I'm looking for a tensor product (of abelian groups, let's say), and some elements $a{\otimes}b$ and $c{\otimes}d$ such that $a{\otimes}b+c{\otimes}d$ $\neq e{\otimes}f$ for any $e{\otimes}f$.

That is, I'd like to show that **there are sometimes elements in a tensor product that are not of the form $e{\otimes}f$**.

I can't find any examples in $\mathbb{Z}{\otimes}\mathbb{Z}$, or even in $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} ){\otimes}\mathbb{Z}$. (Actually no such examples exist, simply because $b$ and $d$ are integers so you can put them into the first coordinates, then the second coordinates both become $1$ and you may add the two elements.)

I think $(1,0){\otimes}(1,0)+(0,1){\otimes}(0,1)$ is an example in $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} ){\otimes}(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} )$. But to prove this, I have to show that $((1,0),(1,0))+((0,1),(0,1))-(e,f)$ is never a linear combination of the tensor relations. This seems very unwieldy; is there a better method invoking the universal property?

Comment: Hi, would like a bit of clarification.
That post proves that everything in the tensor product is a finite sum of things. I want to disprove that this finite sum always has only one summand. So I'm still missing some kind of 'uniqueness/minimality of number of summands' condition. Could you provide it?

Comment: I think your example looks like a good one.  Can you prove that your tensor product is a free abelian group of rank 4?  The generators would be e_i (x) e_j.  I think the hard part would be showing there are no relations among those.  Once you know that, I think it would be pretty straightforward to prove your element cannot be written as a tensor of the form (a,b) (x) (c,d).

Comment: That was very helpful! I've got it.
I actually found the first half of what you said easier -- I just used that the tensor product is an additive functor. So, Z+Z (x) Z+Z = (Z (x) Z)^4 immediately shows that this is a free abelian group of rank 4, since the latter is canonically isomorphic to Z^4.

In fact I only used the first isomorphism Z+Z (x) Z+Z = (Z (x) Z)^4: for if I suppose my element was a tensor (a,b) (x) (c,d), then this results in a contradiction, namely 1(x)1 = 0.

So I didn't really need to use any property of free abelian groups. Was this pretty much what you had in mind?

Comment: Re @rschwieb, could I get a clarification as to whether my question is really a duplicate? Or would you agree that it's not immediately clear if there is a uniqueness condition on the number of summands?

To be clear:
"If an element is the sum of n tensors v_i (x) w_i, where the v_i and the w_i are linearly independent, then n is minimal with this property."

Obviously if this statement holds then my example above works (with n=2 being the minimal number of summands). I am wondering if this statement holds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  The only part I didn't understand was, how do you know if (a,b) (x) (c,d) = your tensor, then 1 (x) 1 = 0?

Comment: The isomorphism from Z+Z (x) Z+Z to (Z (x) Z)^4 sends (a,b)(x)(c,d) to (a(x)c,b(x)c,a(x)d,b(x)d). So the sum of (1,0)(x)(1,0) and (0,1)(x)(0,1) goes to (1(x)1,0,0,1(x)1). Now suppose that the latter is the image of (a,b) (x) (c,d). In particular a(x)d=0, so 1(x)ad=0, so ad=0. Without loss a=0, so comparing with the image of the sum (looking at the 1st coordinates), we have 1(x)1=0.

Did you have something else in mind when you suggested showing the tensor product is a free abelian group of rank four?

Comment: Thanks again, that makes sense.  I think your proof is exactly what I had in mind, just phrased differently.  I think I would have written the isomorphism as going to Z^4 (instead of to (Z (x) Z)^4) and say it sends (a,b) (x) (c,d) to (ac, bc, ad, bd), and (1,0,0,1) is not in that image.  I think the math is the same in both approaches.